# How to set default col 6 on Tablet on SXA Grid Settings

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client

Now when a column splitter is created, the default grid of 6 is applied on Compact Phones.
As per our requirement we wanted to set default col 6 on Tablet.

I tried below,

Updated default component layout details in the below path. But it didn't work.

/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/Experience Accelerator/Bootstrap 4/Bootstrap 4 Grid Definition

[image]

Please help me in fixing this issue.